# fastest algorithm count number of 3 length AP in array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to solve [this](http://www.codechef.com/NOV12/problems/COUNTARI/) CodeChef challenge:

Suppose We are given an array A of N(of range 100,000) elements. We are to find the count of all pairs of 3 such elements 1<=Ai,Aj,Ak<=30,000 such that

 `Aj-Ai = Ak- Aj and i <  j < k`
 
In other words Ai,Aj,Ak are in Arithmetic Progression. For instance for Array :

```
9 4 2 3 6 10 3 3 10
```

so The AP are:

```
{2,6,10},{9,6,3},{9,6,3},{3,3,3},{2,6,10}
```

So the required answer is 5.

### My Approach

What I tried is take 30,000 long arrays named past and right. Initially right contains the count of each 1-30,000 element. 

If we are at ith position past stores the count of array value before i and right stores the count of array after i. I simply loop for all possible common difference in the array. Here is the code :

```
right[arr[1]]--;

for(i=2;i<=n-1;i++)
{
    past[arr[i-1]]++;
    right[arr[i]]--;
    k=30000 - arr[i];
    if(arr[i] <= 15000)
        k=arr[i];
    for(d=1;d<=k;d++)
    {
        ans+= right[arr[i] + d]*past[arr[i]-d] + past[arr[i] + d]*right[arr[i]-d];
    }
    ans+=past[arr[i]]*right[arr[i]];
}
```

But this gets me Time Limit Exceeded. Please help with a better algorithm.

Comment: "Pairs of 3" should either be called "triplets" or "3-tuples".

Comment: @MarkByers {9,6,3} is allowed

Comment: @Fluvid: Oh sorry, I was just being stupid.

Comment: @A.Webb I'll make a note of that :)

Comment: (Hm, chinese remainder theorem?)

Comment: @biziclop: How do you propose we apply chinese remainder theoram

Comment: I don't know, was just pondering about its potential usefulness.

Comment: @Fluvid Do you have an idea of the required time and space complexity?

Comment: A tricky javascript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/h6pza/

Comment: OP forgets to mention that this is the question from [running contest on CodeChef](http://www.codechef.com/NOV12/problems/COUNTARI/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greatly cut execution time if you make a first pass over the list and only extract number pairs that it is possible to have an 3 term AP between (difference is 0 mod 2).  And then iterating between such pairs.

Pseudo C++-y code:

```
// Contains information about each beginning point
struct BeginNode {
  int value;
  size_t offset;
  SortedList<EndNode> ends;  //sorted by EndNode.value
};

// Contains information about each class of end point
struct EndNode {
  int value;
  List<size_t> offsets; // will be sorted without effort due to how we collect offsets
};

struct Result {
  size_t begin;
  size_t middle;
  size_t end;
};

SortedList<BeginNode> nodeList;
foreach (auto i : baseList) {
  BeginNode begin;
  node.value = i;
  node.offset = i's offset; //you'll need to use old school for (i=0;etc;i++) with this
  // baseList is the list between begin and end-2 (inclusive)
  foreach (auto j : restList) { 
    // restList is the list between iterator i+2 and end (inclusive)
    // we do not need to consider i+1, because not enough space for AP
    if ((i-j)%2 == 0) { //if it's possible to have a 3 term AP between these two nodes
      size_t listOffset = binarySearch(begin.ends);
      if (listOffset is valid) {
        begin.ends[listOffset].offsets.push_back(offsets);
      } else {
        EndNode end;
        end.value = j;
        end.offsets.push_back(j's offset);
        begin.ends.sorted_insert(end);
      }
    }
  }
  if (begin has shit in it) {
    nodeList.sorted_insert(begin);
  }
}
// Collection done, now iterate over collection

List<Result> res;
foreach (auto node : nodeList) {
  foreach (auto endNode : node.ends) {
    foreach (value : sublist from node.offset until endNode.offsets.last()) {
      if (value == average(node.value, endNode.value)) {
        // binary_search here to determine how many offsets in "endNode.offsets" "value's offset" is less than.
        do this that many times:
          res.push_back({node.value, value, endNode.value});
      }
    }
  }
}

return res;
```

Comment: could you elaborate a little plz

Comment: While the Entity codes, I think I can explain what it's saying. If `Aj-Ai = Ak- Aj` then `2 Aj = Ak - Ai`, so only pairs with an even difference are candidates for being the ends of a 3-tuple. I am not convinced this will help much in the general case because you'll have a substantial number of even numbers (whose differences are always even) and odd numbers (whose differences are always even). Also, your adversary can take any old array, multiply by 2 and add a (fixed) random number to each and then all pairs have an even difference. But perhaps the Omnipotent has other tricks up its sleeve.

Comment: @A.Webb, I am assuming that the given array is very much like the test array, with several repeats, by coalescing the possibilities in this manner, it's possible to make just one pass over the innermost loop.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity The question is from a running contest at Codchef. Better post your solution to http://www.codechef.com/NOV12/problems/COUNTARI/ , instead of letting fluvid post your solution in his name there...

Comment: I don't care about the contest. :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple C version of the solution that takes advantage of the Ai + Ak must be even test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int arr[] = {9, 4, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3, 3, 10};

int main ()
{
    int i, j, k;
    int sz = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sz - 2; i++)
    {
        for (k = i + 2; k < sz; k++)
        {
            int ik = arr[i] + arr[k];
            int ikdb2 = ik / 2;

            if ((ikdb2 * 2) == ik) // if ik is even
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j < k; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[j] == ikdb2)
                    {
                        count += 1;
                        printf("{%d, %d, %d}\n", arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Count is: %d\n", count);
}
```

and the console dribble:

```
tmp e$ cc -o triples triples.c
tmp e$ ./triples
{9, 6, 3}
{9, 6, 3}
{2, 6, 10}
{2, 6, 10}
{3, 3, 3}
Count is: 5
tmp e$
```

This more complicated version keeps a list of Aj indexed by value to go from n-cubed to n-squared (kinda).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint32_t arr[] = {9, 4, 2, 3, 6, 10, 3, 3, 10};

#define MAX_VALUE 100000u
#define MAX_ASIZE  30000u

static uint16_t index[MAX_VALUE+1];
static uint16_t list[MAX_ASIZE+1];

static inline void remove_from_index (int subscript)
{
    list[subscript] = 0u; // it is guaranteed to be the last element

    uint32_t value = arr[subscript];

    if (value <= MAX_VALUE && subscript == index[value])
    {
        index[value] = 0u; // list now empty
    }
}

static inline void add_to_index (int subscript)
{
    uint32_t value = arr[subscript];

    if (value <= MAX_VALUE)
    {
        list[subscript] = index[value]; // cons
        index[value] = subscript;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int i, k;
    int sz = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sz - 2; i++)
    {
        for (k = i; k < sz; k++) remove_from_index(k);

        for (k = i + 2; k < sz; k++)
        {
            uint32_t ik = arr[i] + arr[k];
            uint32_t ikdb2 = ik / 2;

            add_to_index(k-1); // A(k-1) is now a legal middle value 

            if ((ikdb2 * 2) == ik) // if ik is even
            {
                uint16_t rover = index[ikdb2];

                while (rover != 0u)
                {
                    count += 1;
                    printf("{%d, %d, %d}\n", arr[i], arr[rover], arr[k]);

                    rover = list[rover];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Count is: %d\n", count);
}
```

and the dribble:

```
tmp e$ cc -o triples triples.c
tmp e$ ./triples
{9, 6, 3}
{9, 6, 3}
{2, 6, 10}
{2, 6, 10}
{3, 3, 3}
Count is: 5
tmp e$
```

Comment: I also thought of the same solution but the complexity of the solution is too high. Since n is 100,000 therefore n^2 solution does not suffice