# Efficient way to find the number of all such triplets (from a given set of numbers) whose numbers are in A.P.?

Tags: java, c++, c, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fastest algorithm count number of 3 length AP in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240330/fastest-algorithm-count-number-of-3-length-ap-in-array)

I've been working on the following problem taken from CodeChef's Nov12 challenge. I tried it using the basic formula for checking whether three numbers a, b, c are in A.P., they are if c-b=b-a i.e. 2b=a+c. Here is the problem:

First line of the input contains an integer N (3 ≤ N ≤ 100000). Then the following line contains N space separated integers A1, A2, …, AN and they have values between 1 and 30000 (inclusive).

Output the number of ways to choose a triplet such that they are three consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression.
Example

Input:

10

3 5 3 6 3 4 10 4 5 2

Output:
9

Explanation:

The followings are all 9 ways to choose a triplet

1 : (i, j, k) = (1, 3, 5), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 3, 3)

2 : (i, j, k) = (1, 6, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)

3 : (i, j, k) = (1, 8, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)

4 : (i, j, k) = (3, 6, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)

5 : (i, j, k) = (3, 8, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)

6 : (i, j, k) = (4, 6, 10), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (6, 4, 2)

7 : (i, j, k) = (4, 8, 10), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (6, 4, 2)

8 : (i, j, k) = (5, 6, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)

The code I used is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int scan() {
    int p=0;
    char c;
    c=getchar_unlocked();
    while(c<'0' || c>'9')
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    while(c>='0' && c<='9'){
        p=(p<<3)+(p<<1)+c-'0';
        c=getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return(p);
}
int main() {
    int N, i, j, k, count=0;
    N=scan();
    int a[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        a[i]=scan();
    for(i=0;i<N-2;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<N-1;j++)
            for(k=j+1;k<N;k++)
                if(a[k]+a[i]==2*a[j])
                    ++count;
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
 }
```

As you can see the constraints on variables, it is clear that we need fast and efficient algo. For the sake of safety I even used faster I/O but still the program runs out of time.
It is clear that the algorithm is not that efficient, as I am using three nested loops. One other way that come to reduce the number of some k's is to break the k' loop as soon as a match is found, then I would have added a continue; below ++count and that is working but again NOT that efficient as the problem requires.

Please tell me some fast algo to do this, or if I might learn some mathematical theorem here to find AP triplets quicker.

Comment: Solve for `b`: `b = (a + c) / 2`.  Now just read in the numbers.

Comment: Could you tell why the output is 9? (2,3,4)(3,4,5)(4,5,6)(2, 4, 6), (2, 6, 10) are the 5 triplets... Tell me if I am missing something in this question?

Comment: @Vishal The followings are all 9 ways to choose a triplet
1 : (i, j, k) = (1, 3, 5), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 3, 3)
2 : (i, j, k) = (1, 6, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
3 : (i, j, k) = (1, 8, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
4 : (i, j, k) = (3, 6, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
5 : (i, j, k) = (3, 8, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
6 : (i, j, k) = (4, 6, 10), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (6, 4, 2)
7 : (i, j, k) = (4, 8, 10), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (6, 4, 2)
8 : (i, j, k) = (5, 6, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
9 : (i, j, k) = (5, 8, 9), (Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)

Comment: @Vishal That is, we have to print all such triplets, and NOT only those which are distinct.

Comment: Sunny, in this case you are looking for permutations... N as per my knowledge they are much more than you predicted. only for (3,4,5) there are 12 possible combinations...

Comment: @Vishal but as it seems from the problem and the sample input and output, we have to consider triplets ONLY while moving left to right. That is the example that you gave (2,3,4) do not count here, because here 2, 3 and 4 were chosen randomly, NOT in the same order of the input. Please have a look on the explanation, I have edited the question with that.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity true. thanks. could not notice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an array.

Solve for b from your equation `2b=a+c`, and the result is:

```
b = (a + c) / 2
```

Use 4 variables:  `a, b, c, and counter`.

1. Initialize `a, b, c` by reading the 3 values.
2. if (a+c)/2 == b, increment counter, and print a,b,c.
3. shift variables: a = b, b = c.
4. while cin >> c do:
5. if (a+c)/2 == b, increment counter and print a,b,c.
6. shift variables:  a = b, b = c;
7. end-while.
8. Output value of counter.

Looks very efficient to me.

Comment: Your answer will not give all the permutations...